# PHP Echo Nested Array Value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to echo CATEGORIA Under Booking_meta but nested valued I am not able to echo, here is the print_r results"

I am able to access level 1 array like:

```
echo $EM_Booking-> booking_id;
```

but nested valued inside [registration] and [booking] array I didn't able to echo results, I am little weaker when playing with arrays :)

```
EM_Booking Object
(
[booking_id] => 13
[event_id] => 31
[person_id] => 0
[booking_price] => 0.0000
[booking_spaces] => 1
[booking_comment] => 
[booking_status] => 1
[booking_tax_rate] => 0
[booking_taxes] => 
[booking_meta] => Array
    (
        [registration] => Array
            (
                [user_name] => rb
                [first_name] => rb
                [last_name] => 
                [dbem_email] => walterl81@hotmail.com
                [user_email] => walterl81@hotmail.com
                [dbem_phone] => 33446667678
                [dbem_societa] => ttf
                [dbem_ente] => FCI (Federazione Ciclistica Italiana)
                [dbem_cod_societa] => 6666
                [dbem_tessera_n_] => 3344
            )

        [booking] => Array
            (
                [categoria] => M2 35-39 (nati 1978/1982)
                [dbem_tesseramento] => 
            )

    )
```

Comment: What code did you use to try to access the array values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you have is `Arrays` inside `Object`, so what you can do easily is as follows**

```
// Here is how to access array

// This is your reg array
$reg_array =  $EM_Booking->booking_meta['registration'];

// This is your booking array
$booking_array =  $EM_Booking->booking_meta['booking'];

// Uncomment below if you wanna see array 
// print_r($reg_array);
// print_r($booking_array);

// either through array
echo $booking_array['categoria'];

// Or directly
echo $EM_Booking->booking_meta['booking']['categoria']
```

**OR else**

```
$myobject = json_decode( json_encode($EM_Booking) );

// and then
echo $myobject->booking_meta->registration->user_name;

echo $myobject->booking_meta->booking->categoria;
```

Answer (score 1):

To access data inside [registration] and [booking], you need to write your lines like that:

```
echo $EM_Booking->booking_meta['registration']['user_name'];
echo $EM_Booking->booking_meta['booking']['categoria'];
```

You cannot use something like:

```
$EM_Booking->booking_meta->registration->user_name
```

Because the data stored inside [booking_meta] and [booking] are not Objects. If you look at the dumped data, they are Arrays, so the way to access them is different.